full strong exceptional collection
I am wondering whether, if a triangulated category $\mathcal{D}$ has a full strong exceptional collection (infinite), it is triangle-equivalent to the bounded derived category of finitely generated modules over an algebra?

I think Bondal's 1990 paper "Representations of associative algebras and coherent sheaves" proves the result you ask about, except under two hypotheses: (1) $D = D^b(C)$ for abelian $C$, and (2) the exceptional collection has finite length. To be clear, you are asking whether both of those hypotheses in Bondal's theorem can be simultaneously lifted, right?

Yes, exactly. If $\mathcal{D}$  is not the bounded derived category and the full strong exceptional collection is infinite and not necessarily of finite length, I believe that if the triangulated category is algebraic and has a tilting object, then Keller’s results apply, giving us the desired equivalence. However, in my case, the triangulated category is not algebraic.

Thank you for the references.

I don't know how to deal with an infinite exceptional collection. If you write $E_1, ... E_n$ for the exceptional collection, then Bondal's map compares $C$ to modules over $End(E_1 \oplus ... \oplus E_n)$. You can get something analogous (though only using a generator, not an exceptional collection) in a non-algebraic triangulated category from the main result in Schwede-Shipley "Stable model categories are categories of modules," which assumes a compact generator $S$, and compares $C$ to the category of modules over the ring spectrum $End(S)$. Given a finite set of compact generators,

...you can of course take their coproduct to get a single compact generator. But given an infinite exceptional collection, it's not clear that the coproduct of its members will be compact. In fact you want to get the bounded derived category in the end, so I am not sure you even want to assume that $C$ has all infinite coproducts, so maybe the coproduct of the members of the exceptional collection isn't assumed to exist! So lifting the finiteness assumption on the exceptional collection is well beyond my own knowledge, sorry. I hope someone else knows how to do it.

It is clear that infinite coproducts of non-zero objects cannot be compact.:) I would suggest to present your category as the direct limit of subcategories generated by finite subsets of your excellent collection.
